# Numa balancer in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, numa, numactl

Is NUMA balancer enabled by default in recent Linux versions? If so how can I disable the NUMA balancer please let me know.

Answer (score 8):

The automatic NUMA balancing can be disabled by passing the `numa_balancing=disable` parameter to the kernel. The exact way of doing so depends on the boot loader in use. The same parameter could be controlled via the `kernel.numa_balancing` sysctl:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/numa_balancing
```

or

```
sysctl -w kernel.numa_balancing=0
```

It could also be set in `/etc/sysctl.conf` on distributions that process that file.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on which distribution you are on and the underlying hardware. NUMA should be enabled in the BIOS. To check if NUMA is disabled on your linux use:

```
`grep -i numa /var/log/dmesg`
```

this returns No NUMA configuration found, when NUMA enabled, dmesg does not show any information of NUMA initialization.

If NUMA is enabled in BIOS, then execute the command `numactl --hardware` to list the available nodes on the system.

Note, you can also set `numa=off` to disable in `grub.conf`, but its best to change it using BIOS settings.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I want to NUMA to be enabled in a system. But there is something called NUMA balancer inside the Linux OS, its a daemon if I am not wrong, which will automatically optimize the scheduling on the fly. I just want to know how can I disable it, to avoid the automatic balancing.

Comment: We can disable the numa balancer using echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/numa_balancing

Comment: Yes, but setting "numa=off" in grub.conf more persistent across reboots.